# Finding nth term when recurrence relation is given

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, alternative-proof

$$a_k = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       2a_{k-1} - a_{k-2} &: if \space k > 2 \\
       3 & :if\space k =2 \\
       2 & :if \space k =1
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

It's easy to see that the nth term is n+1 based on the pattern but how do I actually show it? Is there a general way to solve these recurrence problems?

The only way I can think of is $a_k - a_{k-1}=a_{k-1}-a_{k-2}$ implies arithmetic progression, so based on that n+1

Comment: It’s $a_k-a_{k-1}=a_{k-1}-a_{k-2}$

Comment: So by induction $a_k-a_{k-1}=a_2-a_1=1$

Comment: This is a standard homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients. A good place to read about them is [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more general approach would be to write a characteristic equation

$$x^k=2x^{k-1}-x^{k-2}$$

and simplify this to $$x^2=2x-1$$ which has the double solution $x=1$.

It there had been two distinct solutions $\beta$ and $\gamma$ then a general solution to the recurrence would be $a_k= A\beta^k+B\gamma^k$ and you would find $A$ and $B$ by looking at the initial terms.  But if there a double solution $\beta$ to the characteristic equation then a general solution to the recurrence would be $a_k= A\beta^k+Bk\beta^k$. With longer linear recurrences, there may be more roots, and a similar approach works.

Here we are in the latter situation and $\beta=1$, so the solution is of the form $a_k=A+Bk$, and the initial terms $a_1=2, a_2=3$ tell us $A=1, B=1$ and thus $$a_k=1+k.$$